# example of an ideal $I$ in an integral domain $A$ for which there is a prime in $\text{Ass}(A/I)$ that is not in $\text{Ass}(A)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

What is an example of an ideal $I$ in an integral domain $A$ for which there is a prime in $\text{Ass}(A/I)$ that is not in $\text{Ass}(A)$? I've tried constructing one, but all my attempts have failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field and consider the polynomial ring $R=k[x]$. $R$ is an integral domain and so $Ass_R(R)=\left\{0\right\}$. Moreover, the ideal $(x)$ is maximal. Now take $I = (x^2)$. The $R$-module $R/I = k[x] / (x^2)$ is annihilated by a power of $(x)$. In fact, $(x)^2 \subset Ann_R(R/I)$. This shows that $Ann_R(R/I)$ is $(x)$-primary. We conclude that $Ass_R(R/I)=\left\{(x)\right\}$.

Comment: Even simpler: for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of an integral domain $A$, $\DeclareMathOperator\Ass{Ass} \Ass_A(A/\mathfrak m)=\{\mathfrak m\}$ while $\Ass_A(A)= \{0\}$.

Comment: @Bernard: Sure but if $A$ is a field then $m=0$, so i would add to your argument that $A$ is not a field. I guess the question was asking for a concrete example.

Comment: @Manos: I indeed implicitly meant a domain that is not a field. But you're right, it's better to say so. Unfortunately, it's too late to fix it.